# Renaming multiple files in multiple folders leads to FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python

I want to rename multiple files in multiple folders at once, but the coding I designed doesn't work.

My code:

```
c_dir = './data/'

for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(c_dir):
    for file1 in files:
        file_name6 = file1
        oldname6 = str(file_name6)
        print(oldname6)
        newnames1 = file1.split('_')[5:]
        newnames2 = "_".join(newnames1)
        print(newnames2)
        os.rename(os.path.join(os.walk(c_dir), oldname6), os.path.join(os.walk(c_dir), newnames2))
```

Error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 指定されたファイルが見つかりません。:
> './data/**M0001******_2022-03-30-00-09-38-487_C000.smm_logs' ->
> './data/2022-03-30-00-09-38-487_C000.smm_logs'

Comment: the probleme is the os.path.join(c_dir, oldname6) could not be found so try to search in your windows explorer the exact path to your file

'./data/M0001**_2022-03-30-00-09-38-487_C000.smm_logs' is not correct i think

Comment: is the path "./data/M0001**_2022-03-30-00-09-38-487_C000.smm_logs" is correct ?
the program stop because he couldn't found this file

Comment: can you try to do "print("Is it File?" + str(os.path.isfile('./data/M0001**_2022-03-30-00-09-38-487_C000.smm_logs')))" you will see if it's the correct one or note

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rename a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71745182/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You use `os.walk()` in `rename()` - and this is big mistake.

You have to use `currentdir` for this. And this is main problem.

You also mess with variables and it makes code unreadable.

```
c_dir = './data/'

for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(c_dir):
    
    for oldname in files:
        
        full_path_oldname = os.path.join(currentdir, oldname)
        print('oldname:', full_path_oldname)
        
        newname = oldname.split('_')[5:]
        newname = "_".join(newname)

        full_path_newname = os.path.join(currentdir, newname)
        print('newname:', full_path_newname)
        
        os.rename(full_path_oldname, full_path_newname)
```